# robots.txt ignore only slug only

Tags: robots.txt

I want to achieve that behavior:

Allow: **/plans** and
Disallow: **/plans/***

**crawl:**
[www.example.com/plans](http://www.example.com/plans)

**Do not crawl:**

- [www.example.com/plans/abcd-edfg-3fdv-3455](http://www.example.com/plans/abcd-edfg-3fdv-3455)
- [www.example.com/plans/3fdv-3455-edfg-avhn](http://www.example.com/plans/3fdv-3455-edfg-avhn)

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
Allow: /plans$
Disallow: /plans/
```

Entries are assumed to have a trailing wildcard so `/plans/` and `/plans/*` are the same thing. However, this also means that `/plans` will also match `/plansandstuff`. This can be dealt with by using `$` which matches "end of path".

See also: [Robots.txt Specification](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt)

Keep in mind that the robots.txt file is advisory and not all crawlers pay attention to it.